# How to make button presser on Python

Tags: python, button

I have a question, is it possible to use python to make it so that when pressing the right mouse button, some key on the keyboard is pressed (for example, the G key)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have a look at the packages [mouse](https://pypi.org/project/mouse/) and [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/), develop some code and go from there. From my understanding both packages have listener and send events which should make it easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best place to ask such question but I'll answer and whatever happens to the thread happens.

From my experience, I think the easiest and most accessible module for keyboard control would be 'keyboard' by BoppreH. I've used it and had no issues. Good cross-platform choice for Windows and Linux, if that's a consideration.

Here are a couple of resources. Should be easy enough to integrate.

A friendly suggestion for next time, friend. Please try looking online first. Happy Coding :)

https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard